# Java - How to get the default font size of a JTextPane

Tags: java, swing, font-size, jtextpane, uimanager

I have a JTextPane, and I'm trying to get the default font size of the JTextPane.

I've tried looking for methods such as `getFontSize()` and `getTextSize()`, but none seem to exist. I'm clearly missing something, so can anyone help out with this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think you want:

```
int size = yourTextPane.getFont().getSize();
```

Or even more generic:

```
Font defaultFont = UIManager.getDefaults().getFont("TextPane.font");
int defaultSize = defaultFont.getSize();
```

Comment: How did you know to use `"TextPane.font"`?